# How to check on windows system if it supporting S5 soft off state and wake up alarms?

Tags: windows, sleep

I searched on MSDN and found [S5 state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564572(v=vs.85).aspx). But i didn't find any command line through which i could still find if system i am having which supports S5 state or not?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /L

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance) *
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I find out if my system supports S5 state or not?

All systems support S5, as S5 is defined as **Full Shutdown**.

---

#### System Shutdown State S5

> In the S5, or shutdown, state, the machine has no memory state and is
>   not performing any computational tasks.
>
> The only difference between states S4 and S5 is that the computer can
>   restart from the hibernate file in state S4, while restarting from
>   state S5 requires rebooting the system.
>
> State S5 has the following characteristics:
>
> **Power consumption**
>
> - Off, except for trickle current to devices such as the power button.
>
> **Software resumption**
>
> - Boot is required upon awakening.
>
> **Hardware latency**
>
> - Long and undefined. Only physical interaction, such as the user pressing the ON switch, returns the system to the working state. The
>     BIOS can also awaken from a resume timer if the system is so
>     configured.
>
> **System hardware context**
>
> - None retained.

Source [System Shutdown State S5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

#### Soft Off state (S5)

> The soft off state is when the system fully shuts down without a
>   hibernation file. Soft off is also known as a "full shutdown." During
>   a full shutdown and boot, the entire user session is torn down and
>   restarted on the next boot. Consequently, a boot/startup from this
>   state takes significantly longer than S1-S4. A full shutdown (S5)
>   occurs when a system restart is requested (or an application calls a
>   shutdown API).

Source [System Power States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)